# Saving monochrome video in nvenc lossless

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, moviepy

I have a very high res, high frame rate video from a monochrome camera (industrial) - at the moment it is saving all three RGB channels, which means before compression the 1:38s video is 9GB+

I'm trying to workout how to get it to only save the one channel, I've checked they are all identical. It seems like an easy win.

I've managed to do lossless encoding, but when I load it it is still coming back as [1000,1000, 3].

I'm using moviepy.

This didn't error, but also didn't work. It did resize, and was lossless nvenc:

```py
clip= VideoFileClip('file.avi')
clip1 = clip.resize(0.5)
clip1.write_videofile("file2.avi",codec='h264_nvenc',threads=28,ffmpeg_params=['-filter_complex','extractplanes=y','-preset',' lossless'])
```

So clearly I'm missing something, thanks in advance.